# implement to function sorting array of objects in Angular2

Tags: javascript, sorting, angular

I am using Angular2, I would like to sort array of objects based on properties in the object. I need to paginate those objects because of limitation of space. So, I do not want to use Pipe in the context of NgFor. I just would like to implement a sorting function before it rendered into DOM. If someone has some information, could you give some guide? All I found was using PipeTransform. So, I am asking you.

Comment: try array.sort() of JS https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: Thank you so much! It helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use underscorejs [`_.sortBy`](http://underscorejs.org/#sortBy) method.

Code example:

```
_.sortBy(arr, function(o) { return o.start.dateTime; })
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It helps.

Answer (score 1):

try [array.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) of JS

> **Example arr.sort()**

```
var fruit = ['cherries', 'apples', 'bananas'];
fruit.sort(); // ['apples', 'bananas', 'cherries']
```

> **Example arr.sort(compareFunction)**

```
var items = [
  { name: 'Edward', value: 21 },
  { name: 'Sharpe', value: 37 },
  { name: 'And', value: 45 },
  { name: 'The', value: -12 },
  { name: 'Magnetic', value: 13 },
  { name: 'Zeros', value: 37 }
];

// sort by value
items.sort(function (a, b) {
  return a.value - b.value;
});

// sort by name
items.sort(function(a, b) {
  var nameA = a.name.toUpperCase(); // ignore upper and lowercase
  var nameB = b.name.toUpperCase(); // ignore upper and lowercase
  if (nameA < nameB) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (nameA > nameB) {
    return 1;
  }

  // names must be equal
  return 0;
});
```